# Model form update page show to all register users

Tags: django

I have this page :8000/edit/6/ that show a form to update an exciting model and i logged in as X, if i looged in as Y and try to open that page i can see it and update. So this is with no doubt a big bug and dangerous.

Here is my view code

```
class VideoUpdate(UpdateView):
   form_class = VideoForm
   model = Video
   template_name = 'videos/video_update.html'

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(VideoUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

   def form_valid(self, form):
      messages.info(self.request, _('Event is updated successfully'))
      return super(VideoUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Is there a way to check the model object id with the user id. A simple question from a newbie

## Solution:

Actually there are two solutions that works for me in views.py, one is using the get_queryset method

```
def get_queryset(self):
    base_qs = super(VideoUpdate, self).get_queryset()
    return base_qs.filter(user=self.request.user.get_profile)
```

or using get_object method

```
def get_object(self):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    if video.user != self.request.user.get_profile():
        raise Http404
    return video
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me but I think you want to restrict a view from registered but unauthorized users. Usually, this can be better achieved in your views instead of your models:

```
# views.py

def edit_form(request, parameter_indicating_user):
  user = request.user

  if #some logic:
    # if user is equal to the user indicated by some parameter 
    # (id, username, etc) then allow that view to be rendered
  else:
    raise Http404 # or redirect the unauthorized user
```

Comment: Yes this is what i want the owner who just can access the update page as usual. So should i replace this function with the VideoUpdate class

Comment: That's right because as you have noticed, your decorator login_required is not enough, so you need to add some logic inside your view to distinguish between users. Just don't do it in your models because this kind of functionality is better served in your views.

Comment: That's right, i should check if the user id is equal to model instance user id and if so show the page, if no redirect.

Comment: Exactly :-) You can also verify usernames but if you already have an URL using ids, that's ok too.

Comment: If you are going with this method rather than permissions - you do not need to go away from class-based views. Just write a mixin or override  the appropriate method and add the logic there.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your question as meaning the following.

When using class-based views - is there a way to control whether the specific instance of a form is editable by a given user ie. we have record #1 of a model. When you are logged in as user X you can edit record #1, but user Y is not allowed to edit record #1.

If this is what you are talking about you are going to require row/object level permissions, which I have found is best when using django-guardian.

Specifically, when using class-based views you can use the PermissionRequiredMixin, which can be found here: http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/api/guardian.mixins.html#permissionrequiredmixin

If you are looking for just controlling whether User X vs. User Y can edit any instance of that form. ie. User X can edit Form A values. Then you will just need to manage the permissions appropriately and then check if the user has that permission in the view.

JD

Comment: For more explanation suppose i want to edit my twitter profile userX, i go to my own settings page twitter.com/edit/userX, If userY open the same page for userX (twitter.com/edit/userX) he can edit X profile or even delete it. This is what i want to stop doing.If the page is not your own page then redirect to for example homepage

Comment: So for that extra information. Row/object level permissions as I described above is definitely what you are looking for. For an example of the specific scenario you are describing (users and editing their own account) django-userena is an excellent example app and demonstration of integrating the permission required mixin from guardian.